# A kind of “weak” filtered colimit in the effective topos

Tags: ct.category-theory, computability-theory, topos-theory

I was [recently reminded](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448099/when-do-filtered-colimits-exist-in-the-effective-topos) that even filtered colimits in the effective topos generally do not exist.  However, there is an important (albeit restrictive) situation that *looks a lot* like them and that I had hitherto believed to be a colimit.  Let me describe this situation:

**Setup:** Assume $I$ is a partially ordered index set that is filtered (viꝫ. any finite subset has an upper bound), perhaps even totally ordered.  Assume $(X_i, E_i)$ is an object in the effective topos $\mathrm{Eff}$ for each $i\in I$, where $X_i$ is a set and $E_i\colon X_i^2 \to \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is its equality-existence predicate (often written $[\bullet=\bullet]$, but $E_i$ will be more convenient here), and that for $i\leq j$ we are given an injective map of sets $g_{i,j}\colon X_i \to X_j$ which, for ease of notation, we'll pretend to be an inclusion, and also assume that $E_i$ is precisely the restriction of $E_j$ to $X_i^2$.  (Thus, $g_{i,j}$ defines a morphism $(X_i,E_i) \to (X_j,E_j)$ in $\mathrm{Eff}$ in the obvious way, which is clearly a monomorphism.)

Now let $X_\infty$ be the colimit as sets of the $X_i$ (i.e., $X_\infty = \bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$), and let $E_\infty\colon X_\infty^2 \to \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ the unique function on $X_\infty^2$ which extends all of the $E_i$.  This defines an object $(X_\infty,E_\infty)$ of $\mathrm{Eff}$, with obvious morphisms $g_{i,\infty}\colon (X_i,E_i) \to (X_\infty,E_\infty)$ given by the corresponding inclusions of sets.

**Examples of the setup:**

1. With $I = \mathbb{N}$, let $X_i = \{1,\ldots,i\}$ with $E_i(u,u) = \{u\}$ and $E_i(u,v) = \varnothing$ when $u\neq v$ (so $(X_i,E_i)$ is the assembly representing the coproduct of $i$ copies of the terminal object in the effective topos).  Then $(X_\infty,E_\infty)$ is the natural numbers object.  As was [pointed out to me](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448099/when-do-filtered-colimits-exist-in-the-effective-topos/448102#448102) in an answer to the aforementioned question, **this is not** the colimit of the $(X_i,E_i)$.
2. With $I$ being an initial segment of the ordinals, let $X_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} \mathscr{P}(X_{\beta} \times \mathbb{N})$ (seen as functions $X_\beta \to \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$, extended with the value $\varnothing$ as necessary), and $$E_{\alpha+1}(u,v) = \bigcap_{x,y\in X_\alpha}(E_{\alpha}(x,y) \rightarrow (u(x) \leftrightarrow v(y)))$$ (denoting $P\rightarrow Q$ the set of codes of recursive functions total on $P$ and having values in $Q$, and $P\leftrightarrow Q$ the set of codes of pairs of elements of $P\rightarrow Q$ and $Q\rightarrow P$) so that $(X_{\alpha+1}, E_{\alpha+1})$ is the power-object of $(X_{\alpha}, E_{\alpha})$ and this constructs a von Neumann-like hierarchy in $\mathrm{Eff}$ that is essentially due to McCarty (see van Oosten, *Realizability: An Introduction to its Categorical Side* (2008), §3.5.1, esp. prop. 3.5.15).  For each limit ordinal $\delta$, we define $E_\delta$ as the extension to $X_\delta = \bigcup_{\beta<\delta} X_\beta$ of the $E_\beta$, so this is as in the setup above.  (I had believed this limit-step construction to be a colimit, but now because of the previous example I don't know.)

**Question:** Rather than describing $(X_\infty, E_\infty)$ by an explicit construction as above, can we define it by some category-theoretical universal property, and/or some internal construction in $\mathrm{Eff}$ that comes as close as possible to saying that it's a colimit (which, again, it's generally not)?  In other words, is there a reasonable notion of “weak filtered colimit” for which we might say that $(X_\infty, E_\infty)$ is the “weak colimit” of the $(X_i, E_i)$?

**Remark:** As I write this, I realize that part of the difficulty of the question is that $(X_\infty,E_\infty)$ **is not determined** by the $(X_i,E_i)$ and $g_{i,j}$ as objects and morphisms in $\mathrm{Eff}$ but generally depend on the details of the presentation.  (In other words, if $(X^\prime_i, E^\prime_i)$ and $g^\prime_{i,j}$ are also as in the above setup, and given isomorphisms $h_i\colon (X_i,E_i) \to (X^\prime_i,E^\prime_i)$ in $\mathrm{Eff}$ such that $g^\prime_{i,j}\circ h_i = h_j\circ g_{i,j}$, there may not be an isomorphism $h_\infty \colon (X_\infty,E_\infty) \to (X^\prime_\infty,E^\prime_\infty)$ such that $g^\prime_{i,\infty}\circ h_i = h_\infty\circ g_{i,\infty}$.  To see this, consider two copies of the first example above for even $i$ only, let $h_\infty \colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a non-recursive bijection that restricts to a bijection $h_i$ of $\{1,\ldots,i\}$ for every even $i$: then the $h_i$ are compatible automorphisms of $(X_i,E_i)$ in $\mathrm{Eff}$, but they do not give rise to an automomorphism of $(X_\infty,E_\infty)$.)  So I guess the crucial part of the question is: *what extra data* should we add in $\mathrm{Eff}$ besides the $(X_i,E_i)$ and $g_{i,j}$ as objects and morphisms to reconstruct the setup from which we can build $(X_\infty, E_\infty)$?